# How to find the creation date/time of btrfs snapshots

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

Is there a general way to find the creation date of btrfs snapshots, or is it necessary to encode the date in the snapshot name, as it is e.g. done by [Timeshift](https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
btrfs subvol show {path}
```

You can grep for Creation time.

Comment: Thanks! I have now created https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/pull/158 "Mention how to find the subvolume creation time" against the man page.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please mark my man page pull request with a positive reaction.